# How to print the actual response from the API call? In Python

Tags: python, api, testing

I want to test my different env. like DEV,TEST,STAGE,PRODUCTION. The API call for the env. are different. For instance, http://dev.myclient.com, http://stage.myclient.com etc.

So, I want to write the test cases that will go to my specific URL make a search of specific thing and whatever the response come for example. I search for apples and I got 500 results related to that so, I want that result to print and save into text or Json. and same applies for the all different env.

then I will compare all the environments by one each other when I have a raw response data.

**Any ideas how I can do that? In python specifically.**

Thanks In advance!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `requests` library for sending HTTP requests.This isn't a built-in library, so you should use `pip install requests` to install the library.

Here's an example:

```py
import requests

url = "http://dev.myclient.com/"
response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response)
```

The console should now print the JSON response of the request you just sent. For this to work the URL provided should return a JSON string response.